# Selecting a single article from a Panda list

Tags: python, list, pandas

It might be a stupid question but it is driving me crazy. I have a corpus composed by 8807 articles:

```
print(type(doc_set))
class 'pandas.core.series.Series'
print(len(doc_set))
8807
```

From this list, I just want to select the first one. I have tried `doc_set[1]`, but it retrieves 46 articles. Any idea of how to select a specific article? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use [iloc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) locator:

```
doc_set.iloc[0]
```

Docs [`iloc`]:

> Purely integer-location based indexing for selection by position.
>
> .iloc[] is primarily integer position based (from 0 to length-1 of the
>   axis), but may also be used with a boolean array.
>
> Allowed inputs are:
>
> An integer, e.g. 5. A list or array of integers, e.g. [4, 3, 0]. A
>   slice object with ints, e.g. 1:7. A boolean array. A callable function
>   with one argument (the calling Series, DataFrame or Panel) and that
>   returns valid output for indexing (one of the above) .iloc will raise
>   IndexError if a requested indexer is out-of-bounds, except slice
>   indexers which allow out-of-bounds indexing (this conforms with
>   python/numpy slice semantics).

or [iat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html) locator:

```
doc_set.iat[0]
```

Docs [`iat`]:

> Fast integer location scalar accessor.
>
> Similarly to iloc, iat provides integer based lookups. You can also
>   set using these indexers.

PS `iat` should be faster compared to `iloc`, because the latter one does some overhead

Comment: It works @MaxU, thanks! I will accept the answer once I can. What does iloc do?

Comment: @AndresAzqueta, glad i could help. I've added excerpts from the pandas documentation for each locator

Comment: thanks very much for the explanation, it is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have duplicity in `index`.

Use [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html) if you need select first value of `Series`:

```
doc_set = pd.Series([8,9,10], index=[1,1,1])
print (doc_set)
1     8
1     9
1    10
dtype: int64

print (doc_set[1])
1     8
1     9
1    10
dtype: int64

print (doc_set.iat[0])
8
```